# Why does my Google Maps app not send location?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

I have Google Maps installed in my iPhone 6, and I have enabled location history in [Google location settings page](https://www.google.com/settings/accounthistory), but my [Google location history page](https://maps.google.com/locationhistory/b/0) doesn't have records.

How can I turn it on?

Answer (score 1):

Go to;Settings-Privacy- Location Services- Make sure the toggle at the top of the page is "Green/ON"-scroll down to Google Maps and ensure you have checked either "While Using App" or "Always" depending on your preference.

Answer (score -1):

try going to settings - privacy and turn location services on or location services may be somewhere else